# How can external JSON code be used for javascript (and HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I make a link to a certain external API? I don't want to copy and paste the document because the document changes content all the time, and I want my site to be 'live'. After that I also want to know how you can make the content of the JSON (I think it is JSON) usable for calculations in javascript. In case it is necessary, this is an example of the code https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did Google say?

Comment: If you are making the document then you're just going to have to put it in JSON format in the doc. Then you make a standard ajax call to the external file. The output of that file will be the content of that file. Then just read the return value.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the poster is just missing a piece of knowledge of (AJAX / XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Correct. I was talking to @Soviut and the people who voted to close the question. Good luck!

Comment: @Joe I know, but it's important to make sure the OP isn't just asking SO to do their homework for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to retrieve the JSON file from a script. This is generally known as 'AJAX' (Async Javascript and XML although in this case it's JSON).

Since you are using JQuery you can use the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function or more specifically [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Given that this is new to you, you should read up on this carefully. There are issues of JavaScript's asynchronicity, callbacks, Cross-origin resource sharing etc etc.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what to do

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve this data in this way:

```js
function toTpl(date, content) {

  return `<li>
  <h3>${date}</h3><pre>${JSON.stringify(content)}</pre>      
</li>`
}


jQuery
  .getJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', {
    function: 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED',
    symbol: 'MSFT',
    apikey: 'demo'
  })
  .then(data => data["Time Series (Daily)"])
  .then(series => {
  
    return Object
      .keys(series)
      .reduce((res, date) => res.concat(toTpl(date, series[date])), '')
    ;
  })
  
  // RENDER HTML
  .then(html => $('<ul />').html(html).appendTo(document.body))
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```